# Out of range error VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of values in column A in Sheet1 and want to search through the workbook for the values and return the tab name(value will appear in more than one tab). I'm using this code but it keeps giving me a "script out of range error". Can anyone please explain what's going on?

```
Sub Searchtab()
    Dim x, i As Long, WS As Worksheet, R As Range
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        .Columns(2).Offset(1).ClearContents
        x = .Value
        For Each WS In Worksheets
            If WS.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
                For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
                Set R = WS.Columns(1).Find(x(i, 1))
                    If Not R Is Nothing Then
                        x(i, 2) = x(i, 2) & IIf(x(i, 2) <> "", ", ", "") & WS.Name
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
        .Resize(, 2).Value = x
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Does the active workbook have a worksheet named "Sheet1"? Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: Yes, it has a sheet called Sheet1. The error appears on this line `x(i, 2) = x(i, 2) & IIf(x(i, 2) <> "", ", ", "") & WS.Name`

Comment: Put `MsgBox .Address` right after `With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1).CurrentRegion`. Is your `Range` correct?

Comment: When you hit the "Debug" button on error, what is the value of `i` when you hover over it in the code?

Comment: Added the message box and the range is correct, $A$1:$A$759. The value of `i` when the error comes up is 671

Comment: the `UBound(x, 1)`=759

Comment: What's the value that is stored in `x(671,2)` ?  That should be visible in your locals window.

Comment: It's blank. I removed any values past 500 and ran the code again and now I get the same "script out of range" error and the value of `i` is =1